# I need to solve this problem about android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

As you can see here is my problem with android studio I have been looking for solutions 3 days now but I didn't find any

Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1 current version is 5.2.1

Please fix the project's gradle settings.
Fix gradle wrapper and re-import project
Open gradle wrapper properties
Gradle settings

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a good question** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *File > Project Structure > Project* and change your `Gradle Version` there.

Comment: That place is for the JVM version. For Gradle, you have to either edit the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` (if you have it), or configure IntelliJ to use another Gradle distribution through Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Use Gradle from -> Specified location.